# `ntheorem` and `thmtools` seem incompatible

Tags: theorems, amsthm, cleveref, ntheorem, thmtools

I am preparing the setup of the theorem environments for my thesis. I want to do this right before I have say 200 of those environments in my document, since changing them will likely break things at that stage.

What I want:

- `cleveref`. To have uppercase/lowercase references, idem for plurals
- `thmtools`. Since it provides an interface to `cleveref` for defining the plural names
- Properly placed endmarks. So the endmark should appear on the same line as the last line of text (even if it is displaymath or an `itemize`/`enumerate`)

It seems that this is quite hard to do right. `ntheorem` is quite good at putting thmmarks in the right place, but I can not get `ntheorem` to work right with `thmtools`.

---

At the moment I have `thmtools` with `amsthm` as backend. This works nicely together with `cleveref`.

I have definitions like

```
\declaretheorem[sibling=equation,qed=\text{\guillemotleft}]{definition}
```

But when I end my definition with a list, the guillemet («) is put on new line. Clearly not what I want (-;

When I switch the backend to `ntheorem` I get compile errors of the form

```
\declaretheorem key `qed' not known.
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

---

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\declaretheoremstyle[
         headformat={\makebox[0pt][r]{\NUMBER\quad}\NAME \NOTE}
]{theorem}
\declaretheoremstyle[
         headformat={\makebox[0pt][r]{\NUMBER\quad}\NAME \NOTE}
]{definition}
\declaretheorem[style=theorem,sibling=equation]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=theorem,sibling=equation]{proposition}
\declaretheorem[style=theorem,sibling=equation]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[style=definition,sibling=equation,qed=\text{\guillemotleft}]{definition}
\declaretheorem[style=definition,sibling=equation,qed=\text{\guillemotleft}]{exercise}
\declaretheorem[style=definition,sibling=equation,qed=\text{\guillemotleft}]{example}
\let\proof\relax
\declaretheorem[style=definition,numbered=no,qed=\qedsymbol]{proof}

%% Math macro stuff to make this compile
\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}       % Spectrum
\DeclareMathOperator{\M}{M}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ga}{Ga}
\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Gm}{Gm}
\def\ol{\overline}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
A \emph{group variety over $k$} is an integral group scheme of finite type over $\Spec k$.
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
Let $k$ be a field and $R$ a commutative $k$-algebra.
\begin{itemize}
    \item The varieties $\Ga_{k} = \Spec k[x]$ and $\Gm_{k} = \Spec k[x,y]/(xy - 1)$ are group varieties. Indeed, $\Ga_{k}(R)$ is the additive group underlying $R$, and $\Gm_{k}(R) = R^*$ is the group of units in $R$.
    \item The variety $\M_{n,k} = \Spec k[(x_{ij})_{ij}]$ is a group variety. Also the closed sub variety $\GL_{n,k}$ defined by the polynomial $\det \left( (x_{ij})_{ij} \right) - 1$ is a group variety. The $R$-valued points are the $n \times n$-matrices $\M_{n,k}(R)$ with coefficients in $R$, and $\GL_{n,k}(R)$ consists of the invertible matrices respectively. Observe that $\Gm_{k} = \GL_{1,k}$.
    \item The variety $\mu_{n,k} = \Spec k[x]/(x^n -1)$ is a group variety, and $\mu_{n,k}(R)$ consists of the group of $n$-th roots of unity in $R$.
    \item An elliptic curve over $k$ is defined as a proper variety $E/k$ that is smooth of relative dimension $1$, of which the geometric fibre $E_{\ol{k}}$ has genus $1$, together with a given point $0 \in E(k)$. It can be shown that every elliptic curve is a group variety. Actually they form an important class of objects in the study of abelian varieties.
\end{itemize}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Note that the endmark of the definition is fine, but the endmark of the example is on a line of itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use `ntheorem` instead of `amsthm` as the back-end, then you will have to resign to some of the formatting features that were available with `amsthm` and some other changes will have to be made:

1. The commands `\NAME`, `\NUMBER`, and `\NOTE` will no longer be available.
2. To simulate the desired head formatting, you can use the `headformat=swapnumber` option instead, but then you loose the flexibility to change the head format.
3. The option `qed=\text{\guillemotleft}` will have to be used in `\declaretheoremstyle` instead of in `\declaretheorem` (which, in any case, makes sense).
4. Your `proof` environment will have to be defined separately.

Here's an example of how your definitions would look like using `ntheorem`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\declaretheoremstyle[headformat=swapnumber,bodyfont=\normalfont]{theorem}
\declaretheoremstyle[headformat=swapnumber,bodyfont=\normalfont
,qed=\text{\guillemotleft}]{mydefinition}

\declaretheorem[style=theorem,sibling=equation]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=theorem,sibling=equation]{proposition}
\declaretheorem[style=theorem,sibling=equation]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[style=mydefinition,sibling=equation]{definition}
\declaretheorem[style=mydefinition,sibling=equation]{exercise}
\declaretheorem[style=mydefinition,sibling=equation]{example}

\newtheorem*{proof}{Proof}

%% Math macro stuff to make this compile
\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}       % Spectrum
\DeclareMathOperator{\M}{M}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ga}{Ga}
\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Gm}{Gm}
\def\ol{\overline}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
A \emph{group variety over $k$} is an integral group scheme of finite type over $\Spec k$.
\end{definition}

\begin{proof}
Test
\end{proof}

\begin{example}
Let $k$ be a field and $R$ a commutative $k$-algebra.
\begin{itemize}
    \item The varieties $\Ga_{k} = \Spec k[x]$ and $\Gm_{k} = \Spec k[x,y]/(xy - 1)$ are group varieties. Indeed, $\Ga_{k}(R)$ is the additive group underlying $R$, and $\Gm_{k}(R) = R^*$ is the group of units in $R$.
    \item The variety $\M_{n,k} = \Spec k[(x_{ij})_{ij}]$ is a group variety. Also the closed sub variety $\GL_{n,k}$ defined by the polynomial $\det \left( (x_{ij})_{ij} \right) - 1$ is a group variety. The $R$-valued points are the $n \times n$-matrices $\M_{n,k}(R)$ with coefficients in $R$, and $\GL_{n,k}(R)$ consists of the invertible matrices respectively. Observe that $\Gm_{k} = \GL_{1,k}$.
    \item The variety $\mu_{n,k} = \Spec k[x]/(x^n -1)$ is a group variety, and $\mu_{n,k}(R)$ consists of the group of $n$-th roots of unity in $R$.
    \item An elliptic curve over $k$ is defined as a proper variety $E/k$ that is smooth of relative dimension $1$, of which the geometric fibre $E_{\ol{k}}$ has genus $1$, together with a given point $0 \in E(k)$. It can be shown that every elliptic curve is a group variety. Actually they form an important class of objects in the study of abelian varieties.
\end{itemize}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks! That looks promising. Is it possible to hang these thereom counters in the margin?

Comment: @jmc: sure; simply use `\declaretheoremstyle[headformat=swapnumber,bodyfont=\normalfont
,qed=\text{\guillemotleft}]{mydefinition}
\declaretheorem[style=margin,sibling=equation]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=margin,sibling=equation]{proposition}
\declaretheorem[style=margin,sibling=equation]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[style=margin,sibling=equation]{definition}
\declaretheorem[style=margin,sibling=equation]{exercise}
\declaretheorem[style=margin,sibling=equation]{example}`

Comment: | Right! Somehow that works, but I really don't understand why/how it combines `style=margin` with `mydefinition`. Still the result shows that it uses features of both. Can you clarify this to me?

Comment: @jmc All the `\declaretheorem` declarations that appear right after a `\declaretheoremstyle` will inherit the specifications of this theorem style; it's the way that it's supposed to work.

Comment: Aah, I thought you would have to use the `style=xyz` to assign a specific style to a theorem. Thanks for clearing this up. When time is due, I will award the bounty.

Comment: @jmc: if `amsthm` is the back-end, then you do have to use `style=xyz`.

Comment: Ok, then that is exactly what was confusing me. Now every thing clears up in my fogged mind. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

er, this is a nonworking example.

first problem: `\def\ol\overline` causes a failure with "missing `\begin{document}`"; correct it with braces around `\overline`.

second problem: " Command `\guillemotleft` unavailable in encoding OT1".

in any event, the command `\qedhere` was developed in `amsthm` to address the "new line" problem when a proof ends with a display or a list; it is to be input just before the `\end{...}` command of the embedded element (`equation` and friends or `itemize`).  as it happens, with `thmtools` this will work also for theorem-class objects, but if you want a symbol other than the predefined box, you must redefine `\qedsymbol`

i'm not really familiar with `ntheorem`, but know that it differs in some significant respects from `amsthm`, so if you want to use `thmtools` with `ntheorem` you need to refer to the `thmtools` manual.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know about the `\qedhere` command. However, one advantage of `ntheorem` over `amsthm` is that it is able to "figure out" where the `\qedhere` should be applied on itself.