# Thmtools example & solution environments share numbering with other environments

Tags: macros, sectioning, numbering, environments

Following the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19947/example-solution-environment), I defined example and solution environments using the `thmtools` package, which I want to share numbering with the other environments in my document. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
 \usepackage[margin=.75 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,color,srcltx,enumitem,bm,cancel,thmtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

%Plain environments:
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{result}[theorem]{Result}
%Definition environments:
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
%Remark environments:
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

%Example and solution environments (from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19947/example-solution-environment):
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
numberwithin=section,
sharenumber=theorem
]{exstyle}
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
headpunct={},
qed=$\blacktriangleleft$,
numbered=no,
sharenumber=theorem
]{solstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=exstyle]{example}
\declaretheorem[style=solstyle]{solution}

\begin{document}
\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{definition}
Definition goes here
\end{definition}
\begin{theorem}
Theorem goes here
\end{theorem}
\begin{proposition}
Proposition goes here
\end{proposition}
\begin{lemma}
Lemma goes here
\end{lemma}
\begin{result}
Result goes here
\end{result}
\begin{example}
Example goes here
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I added `sharenumber=theorem`, an idea I got from the [`thmtools` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools). The problem is, adding this causes a LaTeX error "Missing \begin{document}". Removing the line `sharenumber=theorem` makes the error go away, but then I lose the shared numbering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First no need to use `numberwithin=section` in the declaration of `extstyle` as the `example` environment is intended to share the same counter as `theorem`. And `theorem` is already numbered within `section` by its definition. Moreover `numberwithin` key is unknown to `\declaretheoremstyle`. Same is true for `sharenumber` key. This key should be passed to `\declaretheorem` instead of `\declaretheoremstyle`.

1. Don't put `sharenumber` and `numberwithin` in the `\declaretheoremstyle`.
2. Put `sharenumber` in the `\declaretheorem`.

Now the full code.

```
\documentclass{book}
 \usepackage[margin=.75 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,color,srcltx,enumitem,bm,cancel,thmtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

%Plain environments:
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{result}[theorem]{Result}
%Definition environments:
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
%Remark environments:
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

%Example and solution environments (from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19947/example-solution-environment):
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
%numberwithin=section,              %%<--- remove this as it is unknown here
]{exstyle}
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
headpunct={},
qed=$\blacktriangleleft$,
numbered=no,
%sharenumber=theorem     %% not needed here
]{solstyle}
\declaretheorem[sharenumber=theorem,style=exstyle]{example}
\declaretheorem[style=solstyle]{solution}

\begin{document}
\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{definition}
Definition goes here
\end{definition}
\begin{theorem}
Theorem goes here
\end{theorem}
\begin{proposition}
Proposition goes here
\end{proposition}
\begin{lemma}
Lemma goes here
\end{lemma}
\begin{result}
Result goes here
\end{result}
\begin{example}
Example goes here
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use `sibling=theorem` or `numberlike=theorem`

Comment: it's `sharenumber` not `sharecounter` in last line? I think no such key defined by the package!?

Comment: @touhami It is defined according to the manual. Please see page 3, line 1 after the example at the top. I have added a screen shot.

Comment: @HarishKumar It works like a charm. Thanks for pointing out the mistakes and for your help correcting them!

Comment: @EthanAlvaree You are welcome. :)

Comment: I think it's an error of documentation, as you can see your code use `sharenumber=theorem` not one of 3 keys mentionned but it works, however if you try `sharecounter=theorem` you will get error (at least I do)

Comment: @touhami Yes. I too get an error. I will correct. Thanks.