# natbib not displaying myref.bib bibliography page using Overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, overleaf

I have a complicated thesis document that I have been working on, but I cannot get my reference page to display anything. I am compiling in Overleaf. I have attempted using biblatex as well but had no luck. The project is copied from this example with quite a few things changed, and it uses biblatex (couldn't get to work):
https://www.overleaf.com/project/6255ab59c467eb2d8239750f

my main.tex is shown here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{uitmthesis}
\input{settings}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\theconfirmation
\input{frontmatter/frontAuthorsDeclaration}
\input{frontmatter/frontAbstract}
\input{frontmatter/frontAcknowledgement}

\tableofcontents
{%% Adding word 'Table' before each entry in list of tables
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
    \listoftables%
}
{%% Adding word 'Figure' before each entry in list of figures
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
    \listoffigures%
}
\input{frontmatter/listofsymbols}
\input{frontmatter/listofabbreviations}
\input{frontmatter/listofnomenclatures}

\mainmatter
\input{mainmatter/chapIntro}
\input{mainmatter/chapLiterature}
\input{mainmatter/chapMethodology}
\input{mainmatter/chapResults}
\input{mainmatter/chapConclusion}

\bibliography{myref}

\begin{appendix}
\appendixpage

% Remove Appendices from ToC. Important: Do not enable.
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}

\input{appendices/appData}
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

my settings.tex is here (anything commented %me is an addition that I have made to the project):

```
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{multirow} % me
\usepackage{tabularx}  % me
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % me

%% Mathematics related
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage{pgfplots} % me
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9} % me

\usepackage{tikz} % me
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % me
\usepackage{capt-of} % me
\usepackage{tabu} % me
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % me

%% Images
% define images locations.
\graphicspath{{mainmatter/images/},{appendices/images/}}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[english]{babel} % me
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib} % me
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} % me


\usepackage{memhfixc} % add memhfixc to use hyperref package
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,bookmarksdepth=4,hidelinks,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}

%==================================================================%
% Theorem, corollary, lemma, remark, definition, example, solution %
%==================================================================%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
%\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{definition}\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
%% Solution environment
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19948/2405
\newenvironment{solution}{%
    \let\oldqedsymbol=\qedsymbol%
    \def\@addpunct##1{}%
    \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacktriangleleft$}%
    \begin{proof}[\bfseries\upshape Solution]}%
    {\end{proof}%
    \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\oldqedsymbol}}
            
%====================================%
% Settings. Please edit accordingly. %
%====================================%
\title{title}
\author{MJ}
\date{June 2022}
\datesubmit{date submited} % viva date for postgraduate / submission date for FYP
\supervisor{Prof.}
\university{University}

\reportType{Thesis} % for postgraduate by research

\degreeAcronym{Honors BSc}

%% Programme
\programmeCode{CS952}\programme{Honors Bachelor of Science}\programmeT{Computer Science}

\gender{male}

%% MISC
\studentid{XXX}
\faculty{Faculty of Computer and Electrical Engineering}

%============================%
% PDF metadata with hyperref %
%============================%
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    pdfinfo={
        Title={\@title},
        Author={\@author},
    }
}
\makeatother
```

Here is my myref.bib file which is in the root directory with main.tex:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

When I compile, there are no glaring errors and the references page just displays the title 'References', so it is attempting to at least compile and load the references page, but is failing to do so.

I do not think any other information for the project is relevant, but if you would like to take a look at the entire project on Overleaf I can send a link to you directly.

I think it might be a package dependency or conflict issue, but I am not sure. The example I have added a link to above works just fine with the references, but I may have edited to many things that the project no longer can compile my references page correctly, I am not sure. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you run BibTeX inbetween LaTeX runs?

Comment: you have posted _lots_ of code but almost none of it is related to bibliographies and we can not use it at all as it references files not shown, Please make an example without all the input files but with a `\cite` that does not appear.

Comment: @Mico not on overleaf, they use `latexmk` so bibtex runs itself, but only if you have `\cite` and don't have errors that stop the job.....

Comment: May I suggest removing the link to your Overleaf project? Since this is not a sharing link, no one can access it, but still, I wouldn't recommend posting it (or your sharing links for that matter) here. If you think this is an Overleaf specific issue, please get in touch with Overleaf support: support@overleaf.com.

Comment: just having a bib file will not generate a bibliography, do you reference it with`\bibliography{myref}` and do you have a `\cite{einstein}`  you need both those things and the code you have shown has no `\cite`